# How to set parameters of hive in hive on spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parameters, hive, config

I use hive in spark, write Scala codes, execute hive sql through hive context, and submit jars by submit script provided by spark.I can set parameters of spark by adding

```
/xx/xx/spark-submit --conf "xxx.xxx=xx" ...
```

in start script of my project.

But how can I set parameters like hive.groupby.skewindata=true in scala codes or in shell script?

Comment: No, you don't *"execute hive sql through hive context"* -- Spark intercepts the SQL (or rather HQL), then some actions are pushed directly to the MetaStore (e.g. `CREATE`) while other actions are processed by Spark itself (e.g. `SELECT` on a Parquet table) and the remainder is pushed to Hive (e.g. `SELECT` on a table with custom SerDe format).

Comment: Cf. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-metastore-parquet-table-conversion if you are not convinced.